# GCP IPSEC Issues

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

Since HA VPNs were introduced it's a nightmare to get tunnels up and working again, the errors do not make sense.

Adding the tunnel to the gateway I get:

> "Invalid value for field 'resource.destRange': ''. is not a valid IPv4 address range"

since when is `192.168.1.0/24` not `CIDR`? Looking at the logs it ends of with:

> "establishing IKE_SA failed, peer not responding"

yet I am looking at the traffic flowing, what did they do?

Created 10 tunnels, 5 work 5 don't.

Can someone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that an internal issue is going on when trying to configure IKEv1 + Route-based VPN tunnels. This will be fixed in the next few days.

If this is your case, as workaround, you can try using either IKEv2 or policy-based VPN.

Comment: I came from IKEv2 tunnels due to them being unstable, tunnel would be up for hours then go down and complain about P2 mismatch, I then manually switch PFS of and it connects immediately.  Then same thing happens, runs for few hours, goes down and the logs say consider using PFS, I switch it back on and then it connects again. It would go through this loop 5 times a day and I cannot work this way.

Comment: I understand IKEv2 is not a valid solution for you, however, the issue with the creation of IKEv1 + Route-based VPN tunnels should be resolved shortly, could you try again?

Comment: This should be no longer happening, however, if so, you can create it through the gcloud command adding the --destination-range [REMOTE_IP_RANGE] argument. You can check [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/creating-static-vpns#creating_a_gateway_and_tunnel) all the detailed steps.

Comment: Thank you Jordi, will test as soon possible